# "No data available in table" VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables, vuejs2

I am building a real time web application. The server runs on Node.js and the client is written in VueJS. I have written an API to fetch player information. When I hit the REST end point, data gets displayed in the form of a table. Although, the data gets displayed right, the first rows says "No data available in table".

[image: Picture]

Here is my code

```js
import urlMixin from "./../mixins/url.js";

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            playerData: "",
            errors:[]
        }
    },

    created: function(){
        this.getAllPlayers();
    },

    mixins: [urlMixin],

    methods: {
        getAllPlayers: function(){
            axios.get(`${this.url}/players`)
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response.data.results);

                this.playerData = response.data.results;

                for(let i=0; i<this.playerData.length;i++){
                    this.playerData[i].image = 
                        "data:image/jpeg;base64," +
                        btoa(
                            new Uint8Array(this.playerData[i].image.data).reduce(
                                (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
                                ""
                        )
                    );
                }

            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e);
            });
        }
    },

    mounted() {

        $(function() {
            $('#player-table').DataTable({
                dom: '<"ui center aligned"f><"ui segment"t><"right-aligned-panel"p>',
                language: {
                    info: "",
                    paginate: {
                        first: "first",
                        previous: "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
                        next: "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>",
                        last: "last"
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    }
}
```

```css
<style scoped>
    .bread-segment {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: none;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template>
 <div class="ui center aligned animated fadeIn" style="padding:20px;">
  <table id="player-table" class="ui small table selectable " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
     <tr>
                        <th>Photo</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Sex</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
     <tr v-for="playerInfo in playerData">
      <td><img class="ui mini rounded image" :src="playerInfo.image"></td>
                  
                        <td><a :href="'#/profile?name='+playerInfo.fname+'%20'+playerInfo.lname">{{playerInfo.fname}} {{playerInfo.lname}}</a></td>
                        
      <td>{{playerInfo.age}}</td>
      <td>{{playerInfo.sex}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

What wrong am I doing? How can I make sure that the text "No data available in table" doesn't appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using jQuery, DataTables and Vue all together. While this is possible to do, the lifecycle functions of these libraries are bound to interfere.

vue community has several table libraries such as https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2

Comment: Thanks Daniel! But, I was able to render static HTML data using the above code. So, I believe the problem is different

Comment: that may be the case, and you can certainly make it work, just pointing out that your solution is going to require additional complexity. you are loading `datatables` on `mount`, and then updating the data.  even though you call `getAllPlayers` on create, due to its asynchronous nature, it will not complete before mount. ergo, you'll not have the data ready in time. Because you have no callback to update the data inside the DataTable after it was created, your table will stay empty.

Comment: but you could move the jquery/datatables stuff inside the `then` response of `getAllPlayers`

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel! I moved the jquery/datatables stuff into the then response. It is working fine now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the context of `this` in the `getAllPlayers` methods by using `function`. Instead, use es6 arrow notation like this:

```
getAllPlayers: () => {
    ....
        this.playerData = response.data.results;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because datatable is processing the table before vuejs.
A trick is to encapsulate your $(..).datatable() in to a SetTimemout JS function

```
setTimeout(() => {
   $(..).datatable()
}, 250) //customize this
```